# Conservation of linear momentum, when is it conserved?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, reference-frames, conservation-laws

1. Will Linear momentum be conserved in a non-inertial frame of reference?
2. In other words what is the fundamental condition for linear momentum to be conserved?
3. Also which is more fundamental- Newton's Third Law or Conservation of Linear Momentum? (as in Newton's third law does not hold true when we go to the quantum/atomic level or at relativistic speeds whereas linear momentum to my knowledge holds true)

Answer (score 4):

Linear momentum will be conserved when the Lagrangian that describes your system is unchanged by translations in space. This is a [consequence of Noether's theorem](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/noether.html), and it's as close as you're going to get to a fundamental explanation for the conservation of momentum.

In general a Lagrangian written in the coordinate system of an accelerating observer is not going to satisfy this condition, so momentum will not be conserved.

I suspect most physicists would regard Newton's third law as derived from conservation of momentum.